# Text Replace in the Java Swing Gui

Tags: java

```
 if (TextArea1.gettext().length() > 0) {
        String TextToChange = TextArea3.getText();
        TextToChange = TextToChange.replace(TextArea1.getText(), TextArea2.getText());
        TextArea3.setText(TextToChange);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text to Replace field is empty", "WARNING", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    if (TextArea2.gettext().length() > 0) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Replace With field is empty", "WARNING", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This is just a dump of code, which makes this question very unclear, and bordering off-topic. Please see [how to ask a good question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/31503)

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Maybe you can change the names `TextArea1` .. to more speaking ones.
- variable names should start with lower case letters (code convention of most java developers)
- `.gettext().length() > 0` could be extracted to a method `ifNotEmpty(..)`
- you could extract a method `showWarning(String msg)`